# Creating and getting saved audio data from child view - iOS

Tags: ios, ios5, core-audio

How do you record an audio in a view and getting the saved audio file after popping out in the parent view?

I am using embedded navigation controller in storyboard.

I have this code in my child view.

```
NSArray *dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];

tempFilePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"record.%@", @"caf"]]];


NSMutableDictionary* recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[recordSetting setValue :[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatAppleIMA4] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey]; 
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];


audioRecorder = [[ AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:tempFilePath settings:recordSetting error:nil];
[audioRecorder setDelegate:self];

[audioRecorder prepareToRecord];

[audioRecorder record];
```

Now, how am I gonna get that in my parent controller?

Comment: Am I recording this right and saving this to Documents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have one view controller recording audio, that view controller should save the audio before it gets dismissed.

And you should save it to a consistent place (e.g. a cache directory, a documents directory, whatever).  And if you give it a predictable filename, you can have your parent view controller easily locate it to load it up again when needed.

Alternatively, you could get a handle to your parent view controller from the navigation controller and pass along either the path to the written out audio data (or a URL), or the raw audio `NSData` object itself.  It all depends on how you've implemented your code.

Comment: Thanks for this answer @Michael. I understand what you mean. How can I get the path of the file after the code above in my parent view?

Comment: In the code you've added above, it looks like you're writing your audio to a file named "record.caf" in the Documents directory.  Just load your audio data from this same location in your parent view controller (that is, if the file exists and can be loaded from) and you should be all set.

Comment: NSArray *dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *tempFilePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"record.%@", @"caf"]]];
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:tempFilePath];
    NSError *error;
    AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
    [audioPlayer setDelegate:self];
    [audioPlayer play]; still got an error when I tried to play in the parent.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a singleton audio controller class to do the recording, and pass that audio controller to every view controller that needs to use audio (record, play, etc.)

Comment: I want to save the audio and later attach it to an email. I have no problems in recording and playing. How can this be done?